# Dynamically Update Android RecyclerView list item on button press

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, listitem

[image]

example:

- load the list using the the B1 view
- user selects B2 dynamically update the list to display B2 view

I would like to update the view without reloading the list or at least bring the user to the previous position.

Is there a way to edit the listitemview without reloading the list?

If so how can to achieve that, if not, is there a way to reload the list in the correct position (the list index)?

I have tried a couple of different ways, but I don't have a clear idea of how to achieve this, any suggestions will be helpful.

Please let me know if you need further details.

Thanks in advance.

```
data class Person(
    val name: String?, 
    val age: Int,
    val dob: String?,
    val height: Int,
    val weight: Int,
    val hairColor: Int,
    val eyeColor: Int )
```

Just as an example let say we have a list of Person's so when the user selects:

- B1 we want to show {name, age, dob}
- B2 we want to show {height, weight}
- B3 we want to show {hairColor, eyeColor}

We want item in the list to change from details -> attrs -> colors but we don't want to reload the list each (or maybe we have to) but the user shouldn't have to re-scroll to the last position.

I just learning kotlin and databinding etc, so I don't if this is possible (i'm sure it is) or what's the best approach to take.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/dataListView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:setData="@{viewModel.dataset}"
app:setListener="@{fragment}"
app:spanCount="3"
tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_1" />
```

Can I programmatically set/reset listitem value? might be a better question.

**tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_1"**

Comment: Why have you used ViewPager? To allow horizontal swiping? And what do you mean by `correct position` here? Are you referring to vertical scroll position of recycler view or just that the list i displayed based on the `B1, B2, ..` selection?

Comment: I have edited the question - best to disregard the viewpager as that is not how this should work.  The correct position is a reference to the index in the list.  I'm trying to get it so that user and change the view to display different details for each item but I don't to force a redraw of the list and then the user has to scroll back to the last position.

Comment: One way is to programmatically scroll to the old position after changing the list. Do you want to avoid any kind of scrolling? Also, are the height and width of each item same in all the four views?

Comment: To answer  "Also, are the height and width of each item same in all the four views? " I not 100% sure but I thinking not as some might included images.

Comment: Then I don't think it will be possible to maintain the exact same scroll position. To get a smooth transition, one solution can be to define all the 4 layout in a single item_layout.xml and show/hide them based on selected view. But that will make the layout bulky. Other solution is to use multiple ViewHolders in the recycler view. And one more that I can think of is to have 4 adapters and switch between them (just keep the previous scroll position and scroll to that on adapter change)

Comment: Thanks Arpit, that pretty much what I have tried: Hide/Show is far too bulky and complex to maintain,  the 4 adapters I ended up creating a viewpager and the multiple ViewHolder I couldn't get to work correctly with databinding, binding adapters etc I think that is probably the correct way to achieve this maybe just need to keep trying.